# Is there any configuartion available to clear uncommitted message during kafka or consumer restart?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I have a business scenario,where the consumers should not consume the committed/uncommitted messages from topic 
when consumer or kafka restart.I tried applying `auto.offset.reset: latest`.But its pulling the uncommitted offsets from topic.For e.g. having an application with one instance with 1 topic and 1 partition.Suppose I posted 10 messages,the consumer picked 5 messages and committed the offset.Now I restarting either my consumer instance /kafka.After restart it should not pick the old 5 messages which was not committed.Looking for any other configuration or workarounds.

Comment: You mean you just want to read the committed offsets but not the uncommitted ones?

Comment: No.Every restart should behave like a clean setup.

Comment: Why don't you use `auto.offset.reset: earliest` then? I don't think you are properly explaining what you want to achieve here.

Comment: I tried refactoring the question.It may help you understand.I was new to this kafka and cloudstream.Sorry for it

Comment: I don't know if it is your wording or just because you are new to kafka but let me clarify something; You call un-committed offsets as "old messages". That's not the case. It is actually the other way around. New messages are considered to be those with uncommitted offset.

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure, that your consumer gets a new Consumer Group (In Java API the consumer config for this is called `group.id`) every time you restart your application. Even if you restart your broker, you would still restart your application with a new `group.id`. And keep the configuration `auto.offset.reset=latest`.

Another option would be to manually change the offsets of the Consumer Group after every broker restart. Kafka comes with a ConsumerGroupCommand tool. You can find some information in the Kafka documentation [Managing Consumer Groups](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_consumer_group).

If you plan to reset a particular Consumer Group ("myConsumerGroup") you can use

```sh
> bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --reset-offsets --group myConsumerGroup --topic topic1 --to-latest
```

Depending on your requirement you can reset the offsets for each partition of the topic with that tool. The help function or documentation explain the options.

Answer (score 0):

Use a unique `group.id` (e.g. a UUID) each time you start, or `seekToEnd` each assigned partition during startup.

See [Seeking to a Specific Offset](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.4.5.RELEASE/reference/html/#seek).